# ESP8266 POSTS successfully and database receives entry BUT empty data

Tags: http, post, arduino, esp8266

I am using the ESP8266HTTPClient library to POST data to my database.  Although there were no errors, and my server responded successfully. When I checked my database, it received an entry, however, it is empty.

I have tested my API with Postman and it completely works.

Code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>

const char* ssid = "foo";
const char* password = "bar";
const char* host ="http://foo.com/";
const char* fullHost ="http://foo.com/api/update";
String PostData = "employeeID=1002&lotNumber=3&lotSize=XS&lotQuantity=46&jobSheetNumber=9&processId=200&timeTaken=30";


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200); 
  delay(10);

// Standard code to connect to Wifi using <ESP8266WiFi.h> library.

}

void loop() {

  Serial.print("\nConnecting to server: ");
  Serial.println(host);

  HTTPClient http;
  http.begin(fullHost);
  http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

  int httpCode = http.POST(PostData);
  String payload = http.getString();                 
  Serial.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
  Serial.println(payload); 
  http.end();

  delay(5000);
}
```

Output:

```
"Connecting to server: http://foo.com/"

"200"

"DATABASE UPDATE SUCCESSFUL"
```

SUMMARY: The data contained in PostData is not being updated into the database despite the successful database connection and entry.

Comment: How are you handling the request on the server side?

Comment: I am using MongoDB as my database and using the Express with node framework to handle the request.

Comment: From what I see there is nothing wrong on the esp2866 side. For me the problem is on the server side but I'm no expert in MongoDB :/

Comment: I see. But I have tested my server with Postman tho. And it works fine :/

Comment: Then there is maybe something wrong with you postData, are you sure everything is written well?

Comment: Yep, I just double checked. It is in the right format and written well.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so I managed to solve the problem. I used MongoDB and Express framework to create the web app. The problem was that I used **req.query.foo** to parse the POST request.

The correct command to use was **req.body.foo**. Thank you all for your responses.